# How to get button name from the controller in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a button:

```
<%= t.submit "#{ t('page.upload_image')}", :name => "image" %>
```

Can I get the name of button("image") from the controller?

Comment: Put in your controller update action  a "logger.debug params.inspect" and see what you are all getting?

Comment: @Rogier it returns me params, but I want to get name of this button

Comment: ah ok. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well this is how i do it:

```
<%= submit_tag "Estimate recordcount", :name => 'count' %>
<%= submit_tag "Download CSV", :name => 'download' %>
```

Then in the controller i check:

```
 if params[:download].present?
 end
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't get html attributes in rails params. 
You need to send it in hidden_field which will be accessible in controller.

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'name', 'image'%>
```

Or you have multiple buttons, then you can write jquery on button click, assign button name to hidden_field and then submit form.

Jquery:

```
$('.submit_button').click(function(){
  var name = $(this).attr('name')
  $('#name_hidden_field').val(name);
  $(form).submit();
})
```

HTML:

```
<%= hidden_field_tag 'name', '', :id => 'name_hidden_field' %>
<%= button_tag "#{ t('page.upload_image')}", :class=> "submit_button", :name => 'image' %>
<%= button_tag "#{ t('page.upload_image')}", :class=> "submit_button", :name => 'image2' %>
```

In both cases, you'll get name in `params[:name]` form.